# Better Python list Naming Other than "list"

Tags: python, naming-conventions

Is it better not to name list variables "list"? Since it's conflicted with the python reserved keyword. Then, what's the better naming? "input_list" sounds kinda awkward.

I know it can be problem-specific, but, say I have a quick sort function, then quick_sort(unsorted_list) is still kinda lengthy, since list passed to sorting function is clearly unsorted by context.

Any idea?

Comment: Nitpick: `list` isn't a "reserved keyword" (I assume you mean "reserved identifier" or "keyword"), it's just a regular identifier... it just happens to be used by a builtin type.

Comment: Python does tend to get pretty wordy at times.  The designers generally choose readability over conciseness, although take a look at list comprehensions for a counterexample.  So don't worry too much about how much you have to type, because it's hard to fight and good for readability.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I like to name it with the plural of whatever's in it.  So, for example, if I have a list of names, I call it `names`, and then I can write:

```
for name in names:
```

which I think looks pretty nice.  But generally for your own sanity you should name your variables so that you can know what they are just from the name.  This convention has the added benefit of being type-agnostic, just like Python itself, because `names` can be any iterable object such as a tuple, a dict, or your very own custom (iterable) object.  You can use `for name in names` on any of those, and if you had a tuple called `names_list` that would just be weird.

(Added from a comment below:) There are a few situations where you don't have to do this.  Using a canonical variable like `i` to index a short loop is OK because `i` is usually used that way.  If your variable is used on more than one page worth of code, so that you can't see its entire lifetime at once, you should give it a sensible name.

Comment: +1 and if there's nothing specific (e.g. a generic `slice` function), there are plenty generic names - `xs/ys/zs` for the mathematically inclined (quite popular in some functional programming languages), `objs`, `items`, etc.

Comment: I feel like it's also Pythonic, although I can't point to the exact guideline.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would you do if you had a list of sheep (or any other thing that doesn't change when going singular -> plural)?

Comment: @Kevin Hahaha good point. There are other conventions that can work like `sheep_list` or `sheep_arr`. If it were code that no one else was likely to look at I'd probably use `sheeps` for a laugh.

Comment: `flock_of_sheep`, but just `goats`, as `flock_of_goats` is not pythonic.

Comment: What about the usecase of OP? Is `quicksort(ints)` really better than `quicksort(L)`?

Answer (score 6):

```
goats
```

Variable names should refer what they are not just what type they are.

Answer (score 6):

Python stands for readability. So basically you should name variables that promote readability. See [PEP20](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020).
You should only have a general rule of consistency and should break this consistency in the following situations:

1. When applying the rule would make the code less readable, even for
       someone who is used to reading code that follows the rules.
2. To be consistent with surrounding code that also breaks it (maybe for
       historic reasons) -- although this is also an opportunity to clean up
       someone else's mess (in true XP style)

Also, use the function naming rules: lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability.

All this is taken from [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Answer (score 3):

Just use `lst`, or `seq` (for sequence)

Comment: That's quite cryptic and not very descriptive. (Not my downvote though.)

Answer (score 3):

I use a naming convention based on descriptive name and type. (I think I learned this from a Jeff Atwood blog post but I can't find it.)

```
goats_list
for goat in goats_list : 
    goat.bleat()

cow_hash = {}
```

etc.

Anything more complicated (list_list_hash_list) I make a class.

Comment: +1 for cow_hash.  That sounds delicious.  Although I would prefer `_dict` for that variable because they're only called hashes in *every other programming language*.  So, not a totally rational reason, but there you go.  It's at least easier on new programmers who don't know how a dictionary works deep down.

Answer (score 2):

What about `L`?

Comment: From now on, I shall adress you as U for "user".

Comment: @delnan Could you please, elaborate why it's a bad practice to use such names? I think this answer is good to be here with the comments why it's not a good idea to use such names.

Comment: My comment is meant as example of why it's a bad idea. `L` for a list - like `U` for a user - conveys no real information, is too short and cryptic, and can't be used to differentiate between several such objects (when you have to store two lists in one scope, how do you call them? `L1` and `L2`?).

Comment: I think there are two things going on here: 1. It's hard to remember shorter variable names. Imagine dealing with a long script where things are named `L`, `l`, `s1`, `s2`, etc. `theList`, `theOtherList`, etc would be at least easier to keep track of. 2. It's easier to remember what a variable does if it has a descriptive name.  `lines` or `crown_list` or `listOfCountries` all make it clear what is in the list. You can probably guess what I was thinking of, and those were made up!

Comment: @delnan OK. Thanks. I voted up your last comment. I'll leave the answer this way with the comments (without editing the answer).

Comment: However, using a canonical variable like `i` to index a short loop is OK.  If the variable is used on more than one page worth of code, where you can't see its entire lifetime at once, you should give it a sensible name.  (Added to my answer.)

Comment: This may sound stupid but this was a good answer for me. I wanted a function that removes an element safely from a generic list. `def save_remove(l, item): try: l.remove(item) except ValueError: pass` So when you actually don't know what's in your list l is a good choice :)

Comment: @Hakaishin Actually while I disagree in general (use something like `lst` to indicate that it is a list), **capital** `L` is significantly better than lowercase `L`, and in fact [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid) explicitly outlines why lowercase `L` is a poor choice for a variable name.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use `unsorted`? I prefer to have names, which communicate ideas, not data types. There are special cases, where the type of a variable is important. But in most cases, it's obvious from the context - like in your case. Quick sort is obviously working on a list.