# How to access Span class or element in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Hi I am trying to access this element span. I want to Access it in a way that it can be appended to a list. every span has a wordnr="1" or any number. I want every `wordnr` into list.

This is what the source code of the site looks

```html
<div id="row1" style="top: 1px;"><span wordnr="0" class="highlight">who</span> <span wordnr="1" class="">other</span> <span wordnr="2" class="">even</span> <span wordnr="3" class="">study</span> <span wordnr="4" class="">near</span> <span wordnr="5" class="">put</span> <span wordnr="6" class="">did</span> <span wordnr="7" class="">up</span> <span wordnr="8" class="">small</span> <span wordnr="9" class="">white</span> <span wordnr="10" class="">go</span> <span wordnr="11" class="">call</span> <span wordnr="12" class="">the</span> <span wordnr="13" class="">big</span> <span wordnr="14" class="">she</span> <span wordnr="15" class="">example</span> <span wordnr="16" class="">part</span> <span wordnr="17" class="">those</span> <span wordnr="18" class="">mean</span> <span wordnr="19" class="">plant</span> <span wordnr="20" class="">down</span> <span wordnr="21" class="">just</span> <span wordnr="22" class="">school</span> <span wordnr="23" class="">still</span> <span wordnr="24" class="">only</span> <span wordnr="25" class="">went</span> <span wordnr="26" class="">thing</span> <span wordnr="27" class="">soon</span> <span wordnr="28" class="">make</span> <span wordnr="29" class="">small</span> <span wordnr="30" class="">when</span> <span wordnr="31" class="">at</span> <span wordnr="32" class="">such</span> <span wordnr="33" class="">work</span> <span wordnr="34" class="">together</span> <span wordnr="35" class="">world</span> <span wordnr="36" class="">like</span> <span wordnr="37" class="">want</span> <span wordnr="38" class="">really</span> <span wordnr="39" class="">her</span> <span wordnr="40" class="">show</span> <span wordnr="41" class="">turn</span> <span wordnr="42" class="">such</span> <span wordnr="43" class="">over</span> <span wordnr="44" class="">hard</span> <span wordnr="45" class="">place</span>
```

Here is my code which does not make sense because I don't know know how to access it or find it. I am using Repl.it so it can be a little confusing looking.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

list=[]

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)


driver.get("https://10fastfingers.com/typing-test/english")

words= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='wordnr'/span[0]]").text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this works:-

```
list = []
words = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@id='row1']/span")
for e in words:
    list.append(e.get_attribute("wordnr"))
```

Answer (score 2):

1 There is "Accept cookies" button. Click it before getting the text.

2 To get the text use `item.get_attribute("innerHTML")`. Not sure why `item.text` does not work for your case. I'll check it later, really interesting.

3 Selenium creates a list for you with `my_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#row1>span[wordnr]")` You do not need to create extra list and append value to it. Furthermore, doing so in your case could lead to a list containing inner lists.

4 Use correct explicit waits. `visibility_of_all_elements_located` won't work because text is only partially visible.

5 Try not to use such identifiers as `list`. It may be a problem for code readability. Check interesting question here [Better Python list Naming Other than "list"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7785071/better-python-list-naming-other-than-list).
**My solution**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver', options=chrome_options)


driver.get("https://10fastfingers.com/typing-test/english")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

#wait for first element presence
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowallSelectionWrapper>#CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll"))).click()

wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[wordnr]")))
my_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#row1>span[wordnr]")
print(len(my_list))
for item in my_list:
    print(item.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

**Sample output**

```
385
keep
country
been
their
food
do
...
```

Prints the whole list (385 words).

Answer (score 1):

There's a accept `all cookies` button. you have to click on it. Below is the sample code :

**code :**

```
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://10fastfingers.com/typing-test/english")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[id='CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll']"))).click()
sleep(5)
for name in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//span[@wordnr]"):
    print(name.get_attribute('wordnr'))
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: This answer is also better than the accepted one, voting for it.

Comment: It's strange that OP has accepted the worst answer among available answers. OP had an issue yesterday, this is super confusing stuff :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the following should work.
Wait until the page is loaded, get the list of relevant elements and then extract texts from each element and append it to the list

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

driver.get("https://10fastfingers.com/typing-test/english")
texts_list=[]
#wait for first element presence
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span[wordnr]")))
#wait for the rest elements loaded
time.sleep(1)

elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("span[wordnr]")
for element in elements:
    texts_list.append(element.text)
```

Comment: It's better not to name a custom list `list`

Comment: You are right, thanks! Updated the variable name

Comment: At least i'll upvote your answer because I do no agree with the accepted one. That approach is very unstable.

Comment: I agree with you as usual :)